# Make menu items and submenu items display vertically without covering each other up

Tags: css, menu

As the first step in making my menu responsive, I want to add a media query in css to change the way the menu displays so that each list item is displayed vertically below the previous item, with it's own submenu items displayed below it before the next list item is displayed. Hope that makes sense.  Here are the HTML and CSS that make the menu work in the desktop version of the site:

HTML

```
<nav>   
<img id="logo" src="@logoUrl">

<ul>

   <li class="@(CurrentPage.Url == "/" ? "current" : null)"><a href="/">Home</a></li>

    @foreach (var item in menuItems)
    {
        <li class="@(CurrentPage.Id == item.Id ? "current" : null)">
            <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>

        @if (item.Children.Where("Visible").Any())
        { 

             var subMenuItems = item.Children.Where("Visible");

          <ul>
                @foreach (var sub in subMenuItems)
                {
                   <li><a href="@sub.Url">@sub.Name</a></li> 
                } 
         </ul>

         }

         </li>
    }
</ul>
<br class="clear">
</nav>
```

(This is on Umbraco, so forgive all the Razor bits)

CSS

```
 #logo {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #354a49;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    padding: 15px 8px 13px 8px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #fefce9;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    font-style: italic;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 200px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fefce9;
    background-color: #a1b0af;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    padding: 20px 3px;
    background-color: #a1b0af;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fefce9;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
    color: #fefce9;
}

nav li.current {
    background-color: #a1b0af;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fefce9;
}

nav li.current > a {
    color: #fefce9;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

And here is the CSS I have in my media query at the moment:

```
#logo {
    margin-right: -50px;
}

nav > ul > li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
}

nav ul ul {
    width: 100%;
}

nav li.current {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

That displays the main menu items one below the other OK, but when I try to change things so that the submenu items appear between the menu items I just end up with the submenu items appearing over the top of the menu items and each other.

EDIT

Here's the rendered HTML as requested:

```
</nav>
  <img id="logo" src="/media/1042/wshalogo.png">

    <ul>

       <li class="current"><a href="/">Home</a></li>

            <li>
                <a href="/about-us/">About us</a>

              <ul>
                       <li><a href="/about-us/our-people/">Our People</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/about-us/who-we-were-and-are/">Who we were and are</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/about-us/our-houses/">Our Houses</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/about-us/annual-reports/">Annual Reports</a></li> 
             </ul>

             </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/being-a-tenant/">Being a Tenant</a>

              <ul>
                       <li><a href="/being-a-tenant/asbestos/">Asbestos</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/being-a-tenant/being-safe-secure/">Being Safe &amp; Secure</a></li> 
             </ul>

             </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/news/">News</a>

              <ul>
                       <li><a href="/news/community-garden/">Community Garden</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/news/football-team/">Football Team</a></li> 
                       <li><a href="/news/health-centre/">Health Centre</a></li> 
             </ul>

             </li>
    </ul>
    <br class="clear">
</nav>
```

Comment: @Pete - edit made as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second level `ul` is `position: absolute;` which means it's taken out of the normal document flow and won't take up space in relation to any other elements. Try changing `absolute` to `relative`. That should keep the items correctly positioned in the menu.

```
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; /* <--- Try changing this to relative. */
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Also, the fixed height on your top-level `li` doesn't let the element grow past `50px`. Try setting that instead to a `min-height`:

```
nav > ul > li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: 50px; /* <-- min-height: 50px */
    float: left;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    padding: 15px 8px 13px 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That worked [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abfoxef/gthhvhce/) but led to awkward jumping when the sub-menu was hovered and then un-hovered.

Also, consider your use-case - if you're doing this to support tablet/mobile devices the `:hover` state won't work the same way it doesn't when you're using a mouse. Users would have to know to press to the side of the "About Us" link text to see the dropdown, otherwise they'll get taken directly to the "About Us" page without seeing the `:hover` state. It might be necessary to either show all the items in a tree structure or use JavaScript to add additional functionality for the submenus.

[Here's a decent solution](https://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-mobile-compatible-responsive-dropdown-menu/) to a responsive sub-menu without JavaScript, but it also doesn't use links for top-level menu items that have sub-items.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Ben, but I've tried that and it doesn't sort it. The submenu items still display over the menu items and each other. Having said that I'm sure I will have to make that change as part of the solution, but it doesn't do the whole thing.

Comment: @Alistair67 Updated with another edit and a fiddle, as well as some additional thoughts/commentary.

Comment: I didn't twig to the fixed height of the top li (obviously) - that sorted it.  I'm going to use javascript to make the menu work on mobile but had to get past this first step, so thank you very much.